# query will run for ages if called by page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have built two queries that are executed in 2 or 3 seconds at most each if run directly in mysql or via phpMyAdmin.

Query 1 in phpMyAdmin says:

> Showing rows 0 - 49 (1945 Total, Query took 3.9455 seconds.)

Query 2 in phpMyAdmin says:

> Showing rows 0 - 49 (901 Total, Query took 2.0582 seconds.)

then I have built a page where I run the queries and print the result in tables

The page is (as all the other pages in my application) open in a container via jQuery load.
If I try to open the page I see that mysql starts running and never stops (minutes). If I stop mysql service the static parts of the page are correctly rendered (table headers). As you can see in the following code the queries have no input parameters or variables that can give an error.

Page code is the following:

```
<?php
try{
    $sql_aperta="
        SELECT veicoli.nome as portafoglio, serie.serie, data_acq,
        Descrizione, cedente, ammesso, prezzo_acq, originator, gruppo,
        COALESCE(sum(incassi_row.importo_inc),0) as flussi
        FROM crediti 
        JOIN azioni_row ON crediti.id_cre = azioni_row.id_cred
        JOIN serie ON crediti.cod_serie = serie.id
        JOIN sofferenze ON crediti.cod_soff = sofferenze.id_soff
        LEFT JOIN incassi_row ON crediti.id_cre = incassi_row.id_cre
        JOIN veicoli ON crediti.titolare = veicoli.id
        WHERE crediti.stato = 'aperta'
        GROUP BY crediti.id_cre";  
    $dati_aperta = $pdo->query($sql_aperta)->fetchAll();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $error = 'Errore ad estrarre i dati: '.$e->getMessage();
}
try{
    $sql_chiusa="
        SELECT veicoli.nome as portafoglio, serie.serie, data_acq,
        Descrizione, cedente, ammesso, prezzo_acq, originator, gruppo,
        COALESCE(sum(incassi_row.importo_inc),0) as flussi, data_chius,
        DATEDIFF(data_chius, data_acq) as coll_time
        FROM crediti 
        JOIN azioni_row ON crediti.id_cre = azioni_row.id_cred
        JOIN serie ON crediti.cod_serie = serie.id
        JOIN sofferenze ON crediti.cod_soff = sofferenze.id_soff
        LEFT JOIN incassi_row ON crediti.id_cre = incassi_row.id_cre
        JOIN veicoli ON crediti.titolare = veicoli.id
        WHERE crediti.stato = 'chiusa'
        GROUP BY crediti.id_cre";
    $dati_chiusa = $pdo->query($sql_chiusa)->fetchAll();
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $error = 'Errore ad estrarre i dati: '.$e->getMessage();
}
?>

<div class="titolo">
    <h2><span id="home">Sofferenze</span> - <span id="home_int">Track record</span></h2>
</div>

<div class="pagina">
    <p><?php echo $data; ?></p>
    <table class="report">
        <caption class="report">Aggregato aperto</caption>
        <tr><th class="report">Portafoglio</th><th class="report">Lotto</th><th class="report">Data acquisizione</th>
        <th class="report">Controparte nominativo</th><th class="report">Cedente nominativo</th>
        <th class="report">Valore nominale ammesso</th><th class="report">Prezzo</th><th class="report">Cedente originario</th>
        <th class="report">Gruppo</th><th class="report">%prezzo/nominale</th><th class="report">Totale flussi</th><th class="report">% flussi/nominale</th></tr>

    <?php
    foreach($dati_aperta as $ap){
        echo '<tr>
            <td class="report">'.$ap['portafoglio'].'</td>
            <td class="report">'.$ap['serie'].'</td>
            <td class="report">'.mysql2table($ap['data_acq']).'</td>
            <td class="report">'.$ap['Descrizione'].'</td>
            <td class="report">'.prot2name($ap['cedente'],$pdo).'</td>
            <td class="report">'.num2cur($ap['ammesso']).'</td>
            <td class="report">'.num2cur($ap['prezzo_acq']).'</td>
            <td class="report">'.prot2name($ap['originator'],$pdo).'</td>
            <td class="report">'.$ap['gruppo'].'</td>
            <td class="report">'.num2cur(round($ap['prezzo_acq']/$ap['ammesso']*100,2)).'%</td>
            <td class="report">'.$ap['flussi'].'</td>
            <td class="report">'.num2cur(round($ap['flussi']/$ap['ammesso']*100,2)).'%</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    <br><br>
        <table class="report">
        <caption class="report">Aggregato chiuso</caption>
        <tr><th class="report">Portafoglio</th><th class="report">Lotto</th><th class="report">Data acquisizione</th>
        <th class="report">Controparte nominativo</th><th class="report">Cedente nominativo</th>
        <th class="report">Valore nominale ammesso</th><th class="report">Prezzo</th><th class="report">Cedente originario</th>
        <th class="report">Gruppo</th><th class="report">%prezzo/nominale</th><th class="report">Totale flussi</th><th class="report">% flussi/nominale</th>
        <th class="report">Data chiusura</th><th class="report">Collection time</th></tr>

    <?php
    foreach($dati_chiusa as $ch){
        echo '<tr>
            <td class="report">'.$ch['portafoglio'].'</td>
            <td class="report">'.$ch['serie'].'</td>
            <td class="report">'.mysql2table($ch['data_acq']).'</td>
            <td class="report">'.$ch['Descrizione'].'</td>
            <td class="report">'.prot2name($ch['cedente'],$pdo).'</td>
            <td class="report">'.num2cur($ch['ammesso']).'</td>
            <td class="report">'.num2cur($ch['prezzo_acq']).'</td>
            <td class="report">'.prot2name($ch['originator'],$pdo).'</td>
            <td class="report">'.$ch['gruppo'].'</td>
            <td class="report">'.num2cur(round($ch['prezzo_acq']/$ch['ammesso']*100,2)).'%</td>
            <td class="report">'.$ch['flussi'].'</td>
            <td class="report">'.num2cur(round($ch['flussi']/$ch['ammesso']*100,2)).'%</td>
            <td class="report">'.mysql2table($ch['data_chius']).'</td>
            <td class="report">'.$ch['coll_time'].'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    ?>
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you are executing it in loop? How much data you have in tables? Have you tried optimizing queries?

Comment: where do you see a loop in this code? Also note that these exact queries, run in mysql directly will take two seconds at most. It is just for this page when run via load

Comment: are you dividing by zero?

Comment: do you see any division by zero (that by the way would be in php not in mysql). the code doesn't throw any error. just the queries keeps running in mysql

Comment: Questions about query performance typically require CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, together with the result of the EXPLAIN

Comment: @Strawberry yes but this time I think the performance is not on the db side (queries are very light) but on how these queries are performed via php. As you can see each query by itself will take around 3 seconds to perform and the performance issue is only when I put the query in the php code

Comment: You have 1945 results for the first query, likely be your browser is choking on creating 2000 table rows. I strongly suggest using LIMIT and some sort of pagination

Comment: @DamienPirsy no. the ajax request performed via .load() keeps performing without returning anything. So it is not on the browser side because the browser has nothing to do waiting. If I stop mysql via terminal the load() complete and the headers are shown (the static html).

Comment: @LelioFaieta Yes, you're not YET rendering the page, but jQuery is BUILDING  a 2000+ html page, and the server needs to send that HUGE amount of html. I bet that's the problem, and LIMITING would solve it

Comment: @DamienPirsy I build much larger tables for this application without any issue! :)

Comment: 4 seconds for 2000 rows is rather unimpressive.

Comment: This is obviously not the whole code for the page, so Justinas and Sam have valid questions. Do the queries EXACTLY copied from your code into MySQL work correctly. Also I would put a LIMIT 1 on it to see if it makes a difference or run it on blank tables. Also comment out the queries to make sure there isn't any invalid PHP crashing the page.

Comment: @BeaverusIV this is the exact code for the page! :) it is the html that will be loaded in a container div

Comment: @LelioFaieta if it is you should be getting an error for an undefined $pdo.